# SSIS Task Script Corrupted On Deployment

Tags: sql-server, ssis, integration, sql-server-2016

The package is well developed and tested in visual studio professional 2015. There are no errors or warning while running the package directly from VS2015. The package is deployed to SQL Server 2016 (SP-1) successfully, now when I run the package the task script task throws the following error.

Error logs:

```
datacode    databytes   message
3           0x          The Script Task is corrupted.
-1073594105 0x          There were errors during task validation.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was very simple solution. My Visual Studio Target was "SQL Server 2017" and I had "SQL Server 2016" once I Changed it to "SQL Server 2016" it got resolved. Works perfectly fine.

Right Click on Project - > Properties -> Configuration Properties -> General -> TargetServerVersion (Drop Down)

[image]